# How to show cart items on cms page?

Tags: magento2, php

**how can I show cart items on any cms page?
So far I created a new block in my module**

```
<?php

        namespace Yoursmartweb\Cinesolutions\Block;

        class CartSidebar extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
        {    
            public function __construct(
                \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
                \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
                array $data = []
            ) {
                $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;;
                parent::__construct($context, $data);
            }

            /**
             * Get quote object associated with cart. By default it is current customer session quote
             *
             * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
             */
            public function getQuoteData()
            {
                $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
                if (!$this->hasData('quote')) {
                    $this->setData('quote', $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote());
                }
                return $this->_getData('quote');
            }
        }

   And I created the phtml

    <?php
    // Get all visible items in cart
    $quote = $block->getQuoteData();

    foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
        echo 'ID: '.$_item->getProductId().'<br/>';
        echo 'Name: '.$_item->getName().'<br/>';
        echo 'Sku: '.$_item->getSku().'<br/>';
        echo 'Quantity: '.$_item->getQty().'<br/>';
        echo 'Price: '.$_item->getPrice().'<br/>';
        echo 'Product Type: '.$_item->getProductType().'<br/>';
        echo 'Discount: '.$_item->getDiscountAmount();echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
    }
```

**And i called the block in the cms page like this**

> {{block class="Yoursmartweb\Cinesolutions\Block\CartSidebar"
>   name="cart_sidebar"
>   template="Yoursmartweb_Cinesolutions::cart_sidebar.phtml"}}
>
> But nothing shows up. Can anyone help me?

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that will work properly since the CMS page will be cached whatever the first state of the page. Once cached it won't show the latest state of cart items.

You need to change the approached and use the knockout JS similar to recently view products.

Comment: I think you are right. maybe can anyone help me getting this done? I have no idea how/where to implement the knockout js... :-(

Answer (score 0):

if you want to bypass the full page cache, you need to implement a punch hole feature.

See https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/punchhole/src/master/

the Model Mbs\HolePunch\CustomerData\ApiData in this repository is the model that will need to contain the quote item info

then the javascript in punchhole/view/frontend/web/js is the place where you will read these data and then you will render these in your template using knockout

this repository was done so that I can have a simple punch hole repo when I need it. Now, this repo does not deal with complex data but hopefully that should help

Answer (score 0):

`<block class="Company_Name\Module_Name\Block\Class_Name" name="name" template="file_name.phtml" cacheable="false" />`

Use cacheable="false" to disable for CMS Pages and you can get all your data display data